# java program to read a String and a character and display the index of the last occurence of the given character without using any built in method

Tags: java, arrays

This is the program I designed to find the first occurrence of the given character, but I want to find the logic for the last occurrence.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test77 {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("\nEnter a String : ");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    char arr[] = new char[str.length()];

    System.out.printf("\nEnter a Character : ");
    char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);


    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
      arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
      if (arr[i] == ch) 
      {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way : don't break when you find the character in the loop. Just store its index.

1. Create a variable to store last found index

```java
int lastIndex= -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {           
    if (arr[i] == ch) {
        System.out.println(i);
        //break;// remove this break.
        lastIndex=i;
    }
}
if (lastIndex > -1) {
    // this is your last occurrence.
}
```

2. Another option is to run the loop in reverse. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the whole array and save the position in a variable.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test77 {

  public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("\nEnter a String : ");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    char arr[] = new char[str.length()];

    System.out.printf("\nEnter a Character : ");
    char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);


    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }

    int position = -1:
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
       if (arr[i] == ch) 
       {
        position = i;
       }
     }
     System.out.println("" + position)   ;

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this idea is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to correct few things in your program and help you understand better way of doing it

1. You used `System.out.printf()` method with a `\n` inside. Java provides you `System.out.println()` method to do this
2. You created a char array `char arr[] = new char[str.length()];` which I don't think is necessary. You can directly check for character using `String.charAt()` method
3. Since you are interested to display the index of last occurrence of a given character, you should iterate from the end so as to achieve better performance

**Example:** Imagine the input String `aaaabbbbbbbbbbbb...100's of b's in between.....bbbbbbbb`. Iterating from front, you have to iterate till the end of char array to determine last occurrence of **b**. Iterating from the back, you just make one iteration thus saving time.

With that said, here is better solution

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test77 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a Character : ");
        char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);

        for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Note:** Your question says without using built-in methods. I assume it is just to determine the last index occurrence. Otherwise, you should definitely use methods such as `length()` and `charAt()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, that printf doesn't matter it will work the same way as println, and sure i m coreecting it.
And as i already mentioned i have to do it without using any built in method that's why i m getting confused else i would have have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as you would a first-occurrence checker, but reverse the loop:

```
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(arr[i] == ch){
    position = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Just like your code, simply reversing the direction - a "first-occurrence-going-backwards" index if you will.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i was just expecting some another way but i'll be we usefull.